# Adding Dynamic drag and drop Form builder not working for angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, formio, angular-formio

I am creating dynamic form builder using angular version 12.

I am using [Angular-Formio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-formio) to create dynamic builder. I have installed the package and follow the steps given in the documentation.

I have installed package with this command:-

```
npm install --save angular-formio
```

Imported into app module ts

```
import { FormioModule } from 'angular-formio';
```

then in import part, I am getting this error.
[image: Error Image]

I don't know why I am getting this error and which package is better to create dynamic form builder(Drag and drop) using angular 12

Answer (score 0):

Your module is not yet loaded by the Angular Server in node ng serve, so restart your server so the server loads the module that you just added in @NgModule app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have installed wrong package

For Angular application, we need to install [@formio/angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@formio/angular) this package.

Steps to install package:-

1. `npm install --save @formio/angular`
2. Add `import { FormioModule } from '@formio/angular';` in app.module.ts file
3. `@NgModule({imports [FormioModule]})`

If you are using angular material then, add [@formio/angular-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@formio/angular-material) this package.

Steps to install package:-

1. `npm install --save @formio/angular-material`
2. Add

   import { MatFormioModule } from '@formio/angular-material';

   import { FormioModule } from '@formio/angular';

   in app.module.ts file
3. `@NgModule({imports [ FormioModule,FormioModule]})`